# datatables passing a js array with objects with key:value

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I am trying to use datatables by passign a jquery object to it. here is what I am working on from [datatables](https://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/js_array.html) and here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/evjhre7n/)

the dataset in the example looks like this(values only):

```
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],...
```

But the dataset I want it to work for is like this(key:value): this is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/evjhre7n/1/)

```
    dataSet = [
    {"Name":"Unity Butler",
    "Position":"Marketing Designer",
    "Office":"San Francisco",
    "Extn.":"5384",
    "Start date":"2009/12/09",
    "Salary":"$85,675"
    },
  {"Name":"Unity Butler2",
    "Position":"Marketing Designer",
    "Office":"San Francisco",
    "Extn.":"5384",
    "Start date":"2009/12/09",
    "Salary":"$85,675"
    },
  {"Name":"Unity Butler3",
    "Position":"Marketing Designer",
    "Office":"San Francisco",
    "Extn.":"5384",
    "Start date":"2009/12/09",
    "Salary":"$85,675"
    }   
    ]
```

I would like to make the change at the datatables end to accept my key:value dataset as opposed to reformatting my dataset to what datatables wants. So my question is, **can this be done?** Or in this case, is it best practice to change the format of my dataset to what datatables wants?

NOTES:
[related Q here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/8355/is-it-possible-to-populate-table-by-passing-json-array-to-datatables)

---

### EDIT1

tks to @Tharsan Sivakumar below, here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/evjhre7n/2/) using map to reformat the dataset.

```
//reformat the dataset above from [{key:value,...},{}..] to [[value,...],[]]
dataSet = dataSet.map(function(d) {
  var arr = [];
  for (var key in d) {
    arr.push(d[key]);
  }
  return arr;
})
```

---

### EDIT2

this is another option
https://datatables.net/blog/2011-05-01

but the data has to be in this format {"aaData": [ {key:value,...},{}...]}

```
{ "aaData": [
    {
        "engine": "Trident",
        "browser": "Internet Explorer 4.0",
        "platform": {
            "inner": "Win 95+",
            "details": [
                "4",
                "X"
            ]
        }
    },
    ...
    ]
}
```

or specific to this example:

```
{ "aaData": [
    {"Name":"Unity Butler",
    "Position":"Marketing Designer",
    "Office":"San Francisco",
    "Extn":"5384",
    "Start date":"2009/12/09",
    "Salary":"$85,675"
    },
  {"Name":"Unity Butler2",
    "Position":"Marketing Designer",
    "Office":"San Francisco",
    "Extn":"5384",
    "Start date":"2009/12/09",
    "Salary":"$85,675"
    },
  {"Name":"Unity Butler3",
    "Position":"Marketing Designer",
    "Office":"San Francisco",
    "Extn":"5384",
    "Start date":"2009/12/09",
    "Salary":"$85,675"
    }   
    ] }
```

I tried to achieve this here in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/evjhre7n/3/) but I cant get access to the files.txt`"sAjaxSource": "files.txt",` there but I have set it up on my server with the directory looking like this(**EDIT3** Here is a github working [example](https://hattricknz.github.io/datatables_example1/)):

```
-index.html
-/sources
+files.txt
```

**Just not sure what is the best option now edit 1 or 2?**

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Data tabes Official](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/20172/single-object-json-to-rows-with-key-as-column1-and-value-as-col2) The rows in the table must be an array - so you would need to use jQuery's map function, or something similar, to convert from your object to an array. The elements in the array can be objects or arrays, but the rows container must be an array.